# Released recordings of The Jive Bombers

Tags: jazz, recording, release

An American group called [The Jive Bombers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jive_Bombers) has come to my attention through listening to the [*Cry-Baby* soundtrack](http://www.allmusic.com/album/cry-baby-mw0000205838). I want to find more of their recordings and was wondering whether there has been any CD or digital releases of The Jive Bombers recordings other than [*Bad Boy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Boy_%28The_Jive_Bombers_song%29) through soundtracks and compilations.

There are many recordings found on [Colorradio.com - The Jive Bombers](http://www.colorradio.com/jive-bombers.html), but none I can find have been re-issued. I’ve searched [allmusic.com](http://www.allmusic.com/) with no luck:

> [image: The Jive Bombers recordings found on AllMusic]

I’ve found [*Jump! With The Jive Bombers*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003SWWA0K) on Amazon, but I’m not sure of its authenticity or whether it’s a recording of the [earlier British band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jive_Bombers_%28British_jazz_band%29).

Comment: Some searching around suggests that what are most likely compilations of the original Savoy 78s by the Jive Bombers were reissued in the 1980s on vinyl, and are offered for sale on ebay and online vinyl sellers like www.cdandlp.com.  No personal experience of dealing with  cdandlp.com, just found some references to it. You may get lucky with this extra information.